# Visual Studio Code extension debugging does not work "Breakpoint set but not yet bound"

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a fresh installed:

- Windows 10
- Visualstudio Code (1.45.1)
- nodejs 12.17.0
- npm 6.14.4

I want to debug a extension with the following settings:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6",
      "outDir": "out",
      "lib": [
          "es6"
      ],
      "sourceMap": true,
      "rootDir": "src",
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      ".vscode-test"
  ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        },
    ]
}
```

The issue that occours:

When I set the breakpoint and start debugging the breakpoint gets greyed out. Hover the breakpoint with the mouse cursor shows a quickinfo "Breakpoint set but not yet bound".

[image]

I have no idea what causes this issue - any help is very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that this is caused by the fact that my extension wasn't activated from the beginning. By activating the extension it did immediately trigger my break point.